# How to save Ping record in every single hour for 2 weeks?

Tags: microsoft-excel, batch-file, ping

how do I save the record ping "in every single hour" for a certain period, for example for 2 weeks, with the format dd / mm / ss, dd / MM / YYYY and beside it is the result of the ping.

So we can monitor our internet connection performance in every hour. Especially in Windows 7

Example of format:

```
30/10/2014 10:55:20 Reply from 103.11.30.57: bytes = 32 time = 3ms TTL = 58
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I perform a ping every X minutes and check the response time?](http://superuser.com/questions/345214/how-can-i-perform-a-ping-every-x-minutes-and-check-the-response-time)

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably be lazy and just make a very basic BAT file:

```
:Ping
ping {whatever it is you are pinging} >>ping.log
sleep 3600
goto :Ping
```

Of course, not everybody has the sleep command, but it's part of Cygwin, and there are probably other ways to "wait an hour".

Comment: You can use `TIMEOUT delay [/nobreak] ` in a batch file ;) See http://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html

Comment: Hmm, I just did "which sleep" and found out my sleep is an .EXE i put in my \UTIL\ folder from GNU ShellUtils 1.9.4 -- I bet that was the late 1990s. Definitely before Cygwin.  This is a problem I have a lot - I solve something before the common solution comes along, so later, after the common solution becomes, well... Common... My solution is now strange :)