# How can I perform a ping every x minutes and time stamp in the log?

Tags: windows-7, networking, batch-file, ping

I found an answer for creating a batch file for continuous pinging:

[How can I perform a ping every X minutes and check the response time?](https://superuser.com/questions/345214/how-can-i-perform-a-ping-every-x-minutes-and-check-the-response-time)

But, I need to include a time and date stamp in the output log.

Would someone help me complete the batch file, please?

```
@ECHO OFF
set IPADDRESS=x.x.x.x
set INTERVAL=60
:PINGINTERVAL
ping %IPADDRESS% -n 1 >> filename.txt
timeout %INTERVAL%
GOTO PINGINTERVAL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set up a log file and provide a time stamp
Need to set a log variable

First up set up log variable and {Setlocal keeps the set command from being permanent }

- Setlocal
- Set LOG=\MyServer\Share\MyFolder\Install_Xyz.log

To send something to the log use >>%LOG%

- echo .  >>%LOG%
- echo Start of install of XYZ  >>%LOG%

to send a time or date stamp use the /T switch to get the bare time output

- Time /T  >>%LOG%
- Date /T  >>%LOG%

Comment: Thank you.  It worked for me.  I will vote for your answer, when I get privileged.  Have a good one!